# Newline in Scheme (Racket)

Tags: string, scheme, racket

It is possible to have a new line when you write with "display" like

```
(display "exa \n mple")
```

But the problem is that there is no any code to have a new line in strings? Like:

```
"exa \n mple"
```

Expected ->

```
exa
 mple
```

What I have:

```
exa \n mple
```

I couldn't find any information in racket-documentation or anywhere else.

Comment: The question is not clear, what do you need again?

Comment: hmmm this works in the racket interpreter on my mac terminal. Are you referring to Dr Racket's interpreter or in racket's interpreter?

Comment: @JasonYeo , dr racket interpreter with racket dialect

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need a way to add a newline between strings, then this will work:

```
(define s (string-append "exa " "\n" " mple"))
s
=> "exa \n mple"

(display s)
=> exa
    mple
```

In the above snippet, I'm using `string-append` for sticking together two strings with a newline in the middle. The resulting string `s` will have a newline in-between when you use it, for example by displaying it.

Obviously it will show up as `"exa \n mple"`, you can't expect the string to jump from one line to the other *unless* you display it, print it, show it, write it, etc.

Comment: Yes but when you work with strings, "\n" doesn't work anymore

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work anymore"? it's working all right, notice that I'm using _two_ backslashes for escaping

Comment: Thus, you mean: If you enter this code: (string-append "bra" "\\n" "va"), you take "va" under the line of "bra" ? 
I'm using scheme with dialect racket and "\\n" doesn't start a new line

Comment: I know that if you use (display) you will have always a new line with "\n" but my question is whether there is a way to add a new line directly in string. Suppose that i will use it to show in a GUI of scheme and therefore new line directly has to be added in string.

Comment: @Asqan that's precisely what my last attempt does: look, you just have to put a "\n" (without escaping it!) between two strings and append them, the resulting string, when displayed, or used will have a newline in-between.

Comment: now i'm okey :) thank you for your answer and sorry for unclear question!

Comment: @Asqan that's all right, it was fun getting to understand what you needed :)

Answer (score 17):

Something like:

```
(display "line\nhola")
```

should do it.

Answer (score 8):

For those that came here looking for how to do something similar to Java's `println` or Python's `print` that adds a newline at the end of the line, racket has a function called `displayln` that does just that. More complicated C-like format printing can be done in Racket with `fprintf`, where it looks like a '~n' gets interpreted as a newline.

Many of Racket's printing functions are documented here: https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html

Comment: `println` works too in Racket!